# VueJS navigates to the root route at first

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have few routes in my router.js. For some reason, before navigating to any route, vuejs at first goes to `'/'` route and only then to the actual route.

Besides, the `'/'` route doesn't have a name or any meta information (even though in the router.js I have a name for this page, `name: home`).

```
fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {}
name: null
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}
```

This is the first route, and after that vuejs navigates where it should navigate.

I suspect the reason is related somehow to the initialization of main vue component, which is:

```
function initApp() {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
}
```

Comment: could you please explain more about question?

Comment: Generally if we mention "mode:history" if url is not matched instead of giving 404 error it will by default gives home page which we set.

Answer (score 0):

Add a route to `/` inside router.js

Here's an example:

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        }
    ]
});
```